# Problem with rhombus

Tags: geometry

We are given that $ABCD$ is a rhombus with sides of 6, therefore $AB=BC=CD=DA=6$ cm, and $ABC \sphericalangle =120^o$, $BM \perp AD$ and $BN\perp CD$. What is the length of $PQ$?

Since $BM \perp AD$ and in triangle $MBD$, $MBD\sphericalangle =\frac{120^o}{4}=30^o$ therefore $MD=\frac{BD}{2}$, how to go from here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\triangle BPQ$ is equilateral with an altitude $BO$ of $3$, so we really have a $30-60-90$ right $\triangle BOP$, with $BO=3$.

Thus $BP=\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}}, PO=\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}, and PQ=PO=\frac{6}{\sqrt{3}}=2 \sqrt{3}$.

This is because the rhombus is a parallelogram, this one has angles of $\angle ABC = 120$, forming equilateral triangles when bisected so you have $BD=AB$, and further, since diagonals of parallelograms bisect one another (and at right angles in a rhombus), you have also $BO=3$. Because $BM$ is perpendicular to $AD$ within an isosceles (equilateral) $\triangle ABD$ it bisects $\angle ABD$ forming $\angle MBD=\angle PBO=30$.

Another way to see this is to realize you could keep tiling equilateral triangles, and see that $AP=PQ=QC$ via symmetries.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\angle ABD=60^\circ$, $\triangle ABD$ is equilateral. In a rhombus the diagonals are perpendicular: $AC\perp BD$. So, $P$ is orthocenter and also centroid. Therefore $PO=\frac13 AO=\frac13\frac{\sqrt3}2 6=\sqrt3$ and $PQ=2PO=2\sqrt3$.